# SQL Server Trigger to send email on insert with conditions and using table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have made a trigger to run upon insert of record, which should first check the current time and if it is beyond a particular hour and minute, it should fire the trigger and should take data from a table and use those values in the subject and body of the email.

Below is the trigger which is working fine but i need to add time condition and I tried to query a table based on the record inserted into the table but I am not getting the desired email.

As you can see that I tried to use a table value to be sent in the subject but I get the email with `SQL Server Message` in the subject.

Another thing I want to add is to query the table and check if the `INSERTED.USERID` is available in the table or not, if it is not available, then no need to fire the trigger.

```
USE [Attendance]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[after_insert_ATT_LOG] ON [dbo].[ATT_LOG]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @PositionCode NVARCHAR(5), @FullNameE NVARCHAR(45), @FullNameE2 NVARCHAR(40), @Email NVARCHAR(50), @EDescription NVARCHAR(100), @ReportingToShortNo NVARCHAR(5), @ReportingtoFullNameE NVARCHAR(45), @ReportingEmail NVARCHAR(50)

Select  @PositionCode=ED.POsitionCode, @FullNameE=EP.FullNameE,@FullNameE2=ED.FullNameE, @Email=ED.Email,  @EDescription=EP.EDescription, @ReportingToShortNo=EP.ReportingToShortNo, @ReportingtoFullNameE=EP.ReportingtoFullNameE, @ReportingEmail=(Select Email
FROM HRSystem.dbo.employeedetails WHERE PositionCode= EP.ReportingToShortNo) FROM HRSystem.dbo.employeedetails ED, HRSystem.dbo.Position EP WHERE ED.PositionID = EP.PositionID AND ED.PositionCode = (Select INSERTED.USERID FROM INSERTED) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'abc@abc.com',
@profile_name = 'Alert',
@subject = @FullNameE,
@body = 'Test Alert';

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH

DECLARE @dummy int
SET @dummy = 1
END CATCH
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `(Select INSERTED.USERID FROM INSERTED)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and all others are ignored. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Also: a trigger should be **nimble, fast, tiny** - and it should **not** contain stuff that does heavy lifting, extensive processing, or time-intensive tasks, like sending an e-mail. This could potentially lead to timeouts in your code, and it's a sure killer of any system-performance you have....

Answer (score 2):

as for your second concern

> Another thing I want to add is to query the table and check if the INSERTED.USERID is available in the table or not, if it is not available, then no need to fire the trigger.

a `FOR INSERT` trigger fires right after a row is inserted. meaning, the `USERID` you wanna look for is sure to be in table `ATT_LOG`.

and as for your first issue. please try the t-sql code below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[after_insert_ATT_LOG] ON [dbo].[ATT_LOG]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @PositionCode NVARCHAR(5), @FullNameE NVARCHAR(45), @FullNameE2 NVARCHAR(40), @Email NVARCHAR(50), @EDescription NVARCHAR(100), @ReportingToShortNo NVARCHAR(5), @ReportingtoFullNameE NVARCHAR(45), @ReportingEmail NVARCHAR(50)

Select @PositionCode=ED.POsitionCode, @FullNameE=EP.FullNameE,@FullNameE2=ED.FullNameE
  , @Email=ED.Email,  @EDescription=EP.EDescription
  , @ReportingToShortNo=EP.ReportingToShortNo
  , @ReportingtoFullNameE=EP.ReportingtoFullNameE
  , @ReportingEmail=
      (Select Email
      FROM HRSystem.dbo.employeedetails
      WHERE PositionCode= EP.ReportingToShortNo)
FROM HRSystem.dbo.employeedetails ED, HRSystem.dbo.Position EP
WHERE ED.PositionID = EP.PositionID
  AND ED.PositionCode =
    (Select INSERTED.PositionCode FROM INSERTED) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'abc@abc.com',
@profile_name = 'Alert',
@subject = @FullNameE,
@body = 'Test Alert';

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH

DECLARE @dummy int
SET @dummy = 1
END CATCH
```

Comment: There is no change in the code, it is same as it is.

Comment: i changed this line `(Select INSERTED.PositionCode FROM INSERTED) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;` you used `INSERTED.USERID` in yours.

Comment: There is no Positioncode in the inserted table, userid is the field to be queried.

Comment: how is table `ATT_LOG` linked to `HRSystem.dbo.Position`? it would be nice if you could provide a sql fiddle of table `ATT_LOG`.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `(Select INSERTED.USERID FROM INSERTED)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and all others are ignored. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: only one row is added at a time in the table.