# Set up email notification every time a threshold value is exceeded within a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, jobs

I have a table where I store errors calculated from a bunch of .csv files that contain prediction and measurements. What I want, is to create an automatic process that will allow me to send an email to my account whenever any row within the table of errors contains a value that exceeds a predefined threshold. I have gone through a lot of documentation online, and as far as I get it I either need to create a **trigger** or set up a **job** on the server. However, I am new therefore I have real troubles implementing what I want. Any example would thus be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Check those:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150162/sql-server-trigger-to-send-email-on-insert-with-conditions-and-using-table-value

Comment: It *sounds* like you want a SQL Server Agent job that queries a table, and depending on the values it finds, sends [database email](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=sql.105).aspx). Loosely speaking, triggers operate on every row change; Agent jobs run every 'n' minutes. This question will probably be closed. Ask another with more code details after you've written some code.

Answer (score 0):

Sending e-mail from a trigger is not a good idea.

Any trigger is a part of the transaction, this means your transaction will not commit until e-mail will be sent, and in case of sending error your transaction will be rolled back.

As you said you can use a job to do this.

In the job you just check for the records of interest and if any row is found, send e-mail from a job. Or you can raise an error if any row is found and make a job send you email on failure.

The job can be scheduled to execute every 5 minutes and you can check for new rows using datetime filed: new rows in the table means

```
datetime_field >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
```